# Extruding two edges in solidworks?

Tags: solidworks

I need to make this structure:

[image]

from this other:

[image]

but I don't figure how, I tried to "Convert Entities", but doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish but I assume it's a raised rib along two outer edges of the bottom image. Many ways to skin a cat in CAD. You could increase the length of you original extrusion to your desired height, then extrude cut back what you need.

Comment: What "didn't work" about convert entities?

Comment: Once you have your sketch from those edges (using convert entities), you can start an Extrude. Then click "thin feature", and make sure it's adding material to the inside of the line. Define the thickness and the extrusion depth, and you're done

Comment: You could also use shell for this kind of thing. Just make override for bottom face thickness.

Answer (score 2):

See below - I don't know what about convert entities is not working for you - it's fine for this application.

It's worth noting, that this kind of referencing to edges is not typically recommended - better to make both the main body and the raised edges from a single master sketch - but there's not enough information in your question to recommend a better modelling process.

[image]

Comment: Thanks to all of you, I finally made it by adding two rectangles in the surface and extrude them, it works fine! Any way I will try your methods!

Comment: There is no one way to do things in SolidWorks, so it is best to experiment.  The built-in tutorials are great for learning new features.